# How can I update variables for many different images in a Javascript canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am new to Javascript in a canvas, and javascript in general.

Basically, what I am trying to do is:

- have many different randomly spawning fire balls (images), that all start at a fixed y value and a random x value.
- They should then fall at a speed of a variable.

I got the random x position, and the fixed y value, but I don't know how I can have a separate falling variable for each new image that tracks it's speed, such as applying this to each individual fire ball:

```
fireBallSpeed = 10;
fireBallTop = 0;
if (randomSpawn == 1){
    fireBallTop += fireBallSpeed;
    fireBall.style.top = fireBallTop + 'px';
    ctx.drawImage(fireBall, randomX, fireBallTop, 50, 50);
}
```

Comment: put each fireball into an array and loop over the array and update each one

Comment: Could you give me an example of that?

Answer (score 0):

You should save each fireball into an array and loop over the array updating each one's position.

```js
let fireballs = []
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

function gameLoop() {
  // Clear the canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 300)

  // Loop over each fireball and update their positon
  fireballs.forEach(fireball => {
    ctx.fillRect(fireball.x, fireball.y, 10, 10)
    // Set the new position for the next frame using the speed
    fireball.y += fireball.speed
  })

  // Request another frame
  requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop)
}

function gameInit() {
  // Create 5 fireballs
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    fireballs.push({ x: Math.random() * 280, y: 5, speed: Math.random() * 2 })
  }
}

// Init the game
gameInit()

// Start the game loop
// This function should only be used for the drawing portion
// and setInterval should be used for the logic
// For simplicity I am going to use this for both
requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop)
```

```html
<canvas width="800" height="300"></canvas>
```